# Exception in thread "Main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Baseball program

Tags: nosuchmethoderror

I am having difficult with a program I am running and when I run the program it says this:

> This program tracks a baseball player's number and their number of
>   hits, walks and outs for each game in a season.
>
> Exception in thread "main" jave.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   Player.setHits(I)I 
>            at BaseBall.main(Baseball.java:71)

Does this mean that there is an error on that line or does it mean that I need to correct something.

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

This means the Player class does not have a setHits() method. You need to look at the Player class and create the setter if it does not exists. Looking at the naming convention it also looks to be a static method.

Comment: For my program I have two things going on. Player.java where I have             pubic void setHits(int h)                                                                                    {
Hits = h;
}

and I have Baseball.java were I have something like this.

while(fin.hasNext())
{
number = fin.nextInt();
int index = number-1;
hits = fin.nextInt();
team[index].setHits(hits= team[index].getHits());

What do I change?

team[index].setHits(h = team[index].getHits());

Comment: @MiloszTomaszewski edit your question post above, with the edit link below it, to add details like that to your question.